# Can't get right portion of middle to stay on the right

Tags: html, css

Okay everybody so basically what's going on is I have my site setup so far with a top portion with my logo then in the middle i want three boxes.  I can get the one on the left to go to the left underneath the top just where I want it same with the second.  But the third when I use float right he wont line up like I told him to.  Can someone please me out with this?  Would really appreciate it!`enter code here`

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/saQataQ/v4YwC)

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=css/animations.css />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="wrap">

        <div class="top_portion">

        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/2a685fsaq.png"/>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="cleft_portion">

        </div>

        <div class="mid_portion">

        </div>

        <div class="cright_portion">

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>

    </head>

    </html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/saQataQ/v4YwC/ Here is the JSfiddle to give a better picture of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .mid_portion is not floated. should also need to be floated left.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your right container before your middle one like this :

```
<div class="center">
        <div class="cleft_portion">

        </div>
        <div class="cright_portion">

        </div>
        <div class="mid_portion">

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just decided to add the float:left like the guy down there advised.  Thanks for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: I hope your center div's width is fix.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to avoid floats and use `display:table`

see  [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4YwC/1/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="center" style="display:table">
        <div class="cleft_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>

        <div class="mid_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>

        <div class="cright_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have removed the `float`s and added `table`  display...its better if you are looking for IE8+ browsers!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
.cleft_portion  {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#3fb9a7;
    float:left;
}

.mid_portion    {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#55948b;
    float:left;
}

.cright_portion {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#3fb9a7;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v4YwC/2/

Comment: Thank you it worked! I'm having such a hard time with floats I really appreciate it!  Hopefully pretty soon I won't be asking such lame questions on here.