# Cannot center div tried floating to left text align margin:auto just wont work

Tags: html, css

Cannot center div tried floating it and using `text-align:center;` `margin:auto` doesn't work please help me I can't figure this out.  I will paste the code and a link for the jfiddle.

It looks fine in Jfiddle but it actually isn't I don't know why. I'm using Chrome
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saQataQ/6DULb/)

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="top_portion">
       <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/2a685fsaq.png"/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="center">
       <div class="cleft_portion">
          <img src="img/5.png" />
       </div>
       <div class="mid_portion">
         <img src="img/css.png"  />
       </div>
       <div class="cright_portion">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom_portion">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: added an edit in my solution,check if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i gave the same solution, in this question of your [Can't get right portion of middle to stay on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834287/cant-get-right-portion-of-middle-to-stay-on-the-right/20834405#20834405) ...considering your markup `display:table` is a better option (*if you can ignore IE8-*)

`display:table` is compatible(*IE8+*) overall with minimal css

see  [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4YwC/1/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="center" style="display:table">
        <div class="cleft_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>

        <div class="mid_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>

        <div class="cright_portion" style="display:table-cell">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have removed the `float`s and added `table`  display...its better if you are looking for IE8+ browsers!!

**EDIT**

**considering your current markup, these might be faults**

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto; /* u have mentioned only auto here */
    width:1200px;
}
```

and add this on top of your css :

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6DULb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

make the width 100%

go to that div you want to center and write:

```
width:100%
```

or play a bit with the widths so that it centers itself

Leave text-align:center and margin:auto;

if it's still not centered you can always play with margin-right/left as long as it UNDER the margin: 0 auto;

also if you are going to do a float best have:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

and play with the height as not to have overlappings

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center` will not work as you are using images in your code.

if you wish to use `margin:0 auto` you should have to give a width to the container which you want to be in center, as the container by default takes the width of the container and `margin:0 auto` applied cant be seen.